# Some [Alt] keyboard shortcuts stopped working

Tags: windows, windows-10, keyboard-shortcuts

Some days ago I noticed that some keyboard shortcuts which include the <kbd>Alt</kbd> key don't work anymore.

**Some examples:**

*Windows Explorer*: <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>↑</kbd> (one directory up) doesn't work, but <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>←</kbd> and <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>→</kbd> (one directory back/forward) do.

*SciTE*: Access keys in the Find/Replace dialog are working for "**F**ind Next" and "In **S**election" but not for "**R**eplace" and "Replace **A**ll" (access keys bold).

*Windows UAC*: When asking for administrator privileges, the dialog's access key for No ("**N**ein" - German language pack) works, that for Yes ("**J**a") doesn't.

What could cause this behavior and how do I get rid of it?

Comment: Have you tried restarting?

Comment: Yes I did a couple of times.